# How to convert high to low frequency data

Tags: frequency, aggregation

I have data for a macroeconomic variable, and it has monthly frequency but I need to work with it in quarters. Is there a statistical method to perform this frequency conversion that ensures the least possible loss of information? Something like a "temporal aggregation" (if that means something).

My time series is unemployment rate, i.e. it is a ratio.

Or an average will make it good? If so, which type of average should fit best?

Also, my purpose is to be as statistically rigorous as possible with the treatment of data.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone with me that this kind of alludes to the Nyquist rate?

Comment: When this variable is a quantity of something, "addition" is a less-fancy name for "temporal aggregation."  Otherwise, when this variable is a rate or some other complex quantity, or a transformation thereof (like a logarithm), the answer must depend on just what kind of quantity it is.  Could you therefore give us some details of your actual problem?

Comment: It's a ratio (unemployment rate).

Comment: If the denominator is not changing much in relative terms (here total number employed or seeking work) then the average of the ratio is likely to be close to the ratio of the average